# reshape rows of numpy array into matrices

Tags: python, numpy, reshape

I have an numpy array `dataArray` with n rows and 10 columns. I want to reshape the first 9 columns of each row into a 3x3 matrix.

If I write `dataArray[i,1]` for a row i, I want to see the reshaped matrix, i.e. `dataArray[i,1]` is supposed to be of size (3,3), and `dataArray[i,2]` is supposed to be the 10th column of the original array, i.e. a scalar.

Comment: what is `dataArray[i,0]` supposed to produce?

Comment: have you tried `data[:,:-1].reshape(-1,3,3)` and `data[:,-1]` to get the 2 parts?

Comment: You start with a (n,10) shape, numeric dtype array.  What you seem to want is a (n,2) object dtype array, where one column is (3,3) arrays, and the other a number.  While possible, that kind of array is not "natural" in `numpy`.  The answers suggest a list of lists, with the array and number in each sublist.  I think two arrays are better, one (n,3,3) and the other (n,).  But what are you intending to do with this?  It looks like a `xtrain`, `ylabel` pair for ML.

Comment: @hpaulj Yes, I want to feed the reshaped data to an ML workdlow. So how would your solution look like then?

Comment: As I described, separate off the last column, and reshape the rest to required dimensions.  The ML docs/tutorials should guide you.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like:

```
n=5
data_array = np.arange(50).reshape(n, 10)
reshaped_data_array = data_array[:, :9].reshape(n, 3, 3)
last_value = data_array[:, -1]
result = [(reshaped_data_array[i], last_value[i]) for i in range(n)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
dataArray = np.random.randn(210, 10)
temp = list(zip(dataArray[:, :9].reshape(dataArray.shape[0], 3, 3), dataArray[:, -1]))
```

This assumes that the first 9 indices are stored as `[[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8]]` and the last value (the tenth) is stored as scalar.

`temp[i]` is then a tuple where `temp[i][0]` is the 3x3 matrix and `temp[i][1]` is the scalar, the values are form `dataArray[i]`.

Answer (score 0):

numpy matrices cannot have irregular dimensions.  So you cannot have one index that contains a scalar and the other one conaining a 3x3 matrix.

regular Python lists can do it however. If you must have a numpy array, you'll have to use np.object as its data type:

```
import numpy as np

data      = np.arange(150).reshape((15, 10))

*dlist,   = zip(data, data[:,:9].reshape((-1,3,3)), data[:,9])
dataArray = np.array(dlist,dtype=np.object)

print(dataArray[3,1])

[[30 31 32]
 [33 34 35]
 [36 37 38]]

print(dataArray[3,2])

39
```

*Note I put the original rows in column zero because you must have a column zero to get a column 1 and 2*